# iOS MDM Profile installation failed. The payload "MDM Configuration" is invalid

Tags: ios, iphone, mdm

I am trying to install the MDM profile on the device but I ran into the problem. Could some one help me get out of this.

The server url which is sent to the device is "https://fqdn:443/"

NSError:

Desc   : The profile “MDM Configuration” is invalid.

Sugg   : The URL specified in the field “ServerURL” must have an https:// scheme.

US Desc: The profile “MDM Configuration” is invalid.

US Sugg: The URL specified in the field “ServerURL” must have an https:// scheme.
    Domain : MCProfileErrorDomain
    Code   : 1000
    Type   : MCFatalError
    Params : (
        "MDM Configuration"
    )

Comment: I'd check if you have the ServerURL tag at the right position and correctly filled. Also omit the port as it's not needed when you're using the standard HTTPS port.

Comment: I hope I am preparing the proper pay load. Tried also without port but no success..